# invalidateOptionsMenu() not working when "restarting" activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an activity, let's call it **FirstActivity.java**, which has an actionBar with a navigation drawer instantiated via fragment. In this fragment, **NavigationDrawerFragment.java**, I've put the methods *onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)*, *onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)* and *onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)* as anyone normally would in order to instantiate the actionBar. On the right side of the actionBar, I have a button with a "messages" icon that leads to the user's inbox fragment. When a new message incomes, I call *invalidateOptionsMenu()* inside my FirstActivity and change the icon to a brighter one in *onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)*. Everything works fine so far.

The problem is: I can leave the FirstAcitivty via one of the options in the navigation drawer. I do it via *Intent*. Let's call it **SecondActivity.java**.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

When I call the FirstAcitivity again, also via Intent, the *invalidateOptionsMenu()* method stops working. It does not trigger the methods *onCreateOptionsMenu* nor *onPrepareOptionsMenu*. I have also tried *supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()* with no luck.

Only when I hit the MENU BUTTON (on the left side of the actionBar) is that these methods are called and the messages icon is changed. Does anyone know the reason for this strange behavior?

Better yet, does anyone know a solution for my problem? : )

**FirstActivity.java**

```
public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity impements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);

//        When a new message arrives
        if (thereIsAnIncomingMessage) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

**first_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/first_activity_layout">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FirstActivity">

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
             this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
             languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
             If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
             android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
        <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
             the container. -->
        <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="com.example.Controller.Main.NavigationBar.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        relativeLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        return relativeLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_menu) {
//            Open navigation drawer menu
            return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } else if (item.getItemId == R.id.action_chat) {
//            Open messages fragment
            MessagesFragment messagesFragment = new MessagesFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, messagesFragment, "MESSAGES_FRAGMENT");
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("chatFrag");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        if (FirstActivity.thereIsAnIncomingMessage) {
            menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.new_message_icon);
        } else {
            menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.message_icon);
        }
    }

    public interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought perhaps _invalidateOptionsMenu()_ was triggering the "old" _onPrepareOptionsMenu_ but fragment back stack entry count is always 0 (zero). Still investigating...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `OnCreate` method of `FirstActivity` is not called when you hit the back button.  Instead, you can put your code in `OnResume`, as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(thereIsAnIncomingMessage)
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
```

See the official [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) documentation.